# How add custom css file in style library in modern sharepoint communication site

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extension

I am customizing share point modern site. when iam uploading css file in styles library its showing deneid message but i am site owner and[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7anuE.png) i have full control right also.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked you permission in the style library? And also [ensure custom script has been enabled](http://blog.timwheeler.io/unable-to-upload-files-to-the-style-library-in-sharepoint-online/) in the current tenant.